# proper application version update that includes database and code update

Tags: yii, version-control, versioning, rpm

I got an application written in YII that from time to time will need version update. Currently, when we release a new update, we manually run a shell script to copy/overwrite the application code/source files from our git repo and set the appropriate permissions and other things, then at the end of the script, we run a YII command to run our database update. We have versioning on our database update. We also rollback changes to the database if one of the sql statements of a version fails. Now the issue occurs if a database update fails, and the application code/source is updated, then it will fail when it tries to access some table fields, table or views.

How to best handle an application update with versioning? Much like the way wordpress handles its update or better.

Would like to ask for suggestions to the rigth approach, it may include RPM, GIT or other info.
It would be good to have a detailed list of processes from you guys.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Database updates may include backups, and running multiple scripts, and
should be handled outside of rpm packaging. There are too many failure modes
for RPM scripting to handle flawlessly.

You can always package up the database schema update script in the package
and then check for the correct schema version when your application starts,
providing instructions (or a pointer to instructions) on how to upgrade the
database, and how to reinstall the last-known-good application, when the wrong
schema version is detected.